# RabbitMq QueueBind somehow use old Routingkey

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, .net-core

I have a setup where the rabbitMq routingkeys are bound with the IModel.QueueBind

The problem I have is that I have changed some code so the routekey is a new value, but when I run the program then somehow RabbitMq binds the old routingkey.

Even if I unbind it from the webinterface then the old routingkey gets bound.

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I will just leave the answer if anyone should end up in the same silly solution.

My setup in the project.json was wrong so I was running against some old dll that no longer was valid.

I guess once code gets migrated to 2.0 the .Net core will no longer be so wierd to figure out.